# Issue with jquery gantt (clashing with cirrus-ui)

Tags: jquery, gantt-chart

I am trying to setup Gantt chart using jquery gantt. I've copied js code, css file and images, already usin jquery from before. This is my code, and it is a very simple version for checking how it would look like:

```
$(".gantt").gantt({
    source: [
        {
            name: "Example",
            desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            values: [
                {
                    from: '2012-02-10',
                    to: '2012-04-03',
                    label: "Example Value",
                    desc: "Something",
                    customClass: "ganttRed",
                },
            ],
            id: 1,
            cssClass: "redLabel"
        },
        {
            name: "Example 2",
            desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            values: [
                {
                    from: '2013-02-10',
                    to: '2015-04-03',
                    label: "Example Value",
                    desc: "Something",
                    customClass: "ganttRed",
                },
            ],
            id: 2,
            cssClass: "redLabel"
        },
    ],
    scale: "weeks",
    minScale: "weeks",
    maxScale: "months"
})
```

I get a chart, but it completely deformed, looks like this:

[image]

I have tried latest version on github, previous versions, etc., but no help, always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after extensive investigation and going step-by-step through code and css it turned out that it is clashing with cirrus-ui css framework that I am using. Now fixed.